# Customizations on UILocalNotification for Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm seeing a lot of resources online that talk about customizing notifications for the Apple Watch. Though I fail to find one that mentions the customization of sound and duration.

Is it even possible for us to customize sound for notification on the watch? I know we can use `localNotification.soundName = "audio.caf"`, but it's not playing/working on my watch. If there is a working solution, could you direct me to these resources?

Also, I want to make a notification duration longer. A workaround to this is to send multiple notifications using the `repeatInterval` like this. But is there a cleaner way for doing this?

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond
```